# Is there any way to filter Hadoop packets when network traffic sniffing?

Tags: networking, hadoop, tcp, packet, sniffing

My objective is to identify network packets related with Hadoop cluster, because in the cluster I'm using there are other services that generate network traffic not related with Hadoop.
I'm assuming my Hadoop cluster uniquely uses HDFS and MapReduce, not other apps like HBase, Pig, Hive, etc...
Is there any way to filter Hadoop packets? For example, if Hadoop uses fix source or destination ports (at least one, source or destionation)

UPDATE: I'm using Apache Hadoop 1.0.3 and libpcap to sniff packets

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Hadoop distribution you're using, or which packet sniffer, but you should be able to take a couple of different approaches here.

Assuming, you're using the default ports for Hadoop services, you should be able to key on the destination port for NameNode and DataNode traffic, as well as JobTracker/TaskTracker.  [This link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_ports_cdh4.html) is published by Cloudera, but they use the same default ports as Hortonworks or any other Apache Hadoop distribution, so the information should be applicable to your use case.

Also, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) appears to have an HDFS protocol [dissector](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/hdfs.html), meaning it should be one of the types it can handle out of the box.  If you're not familiar with Wireshark as network packet analyzer, I suggest you check it out.

Hope this is helpful - good luck!

Comment: Then, I can assume that all the destination ports of all the network connections between Hadoop nodes are known. Consequently, I can filter the Hadoop packets by those known destination ports, right?